# winforms designer problem on a form

Tags: winforms, designer

I have a form that when I open it (double clicking the file in visual studio), loads the designer, shows the form control's and automatically modified the file (without doing nothing) the asterisk is appearing on the file tab, like "mainForm.cs* [Designer]".

Edit: I openned and save, and after saving, y close de form, load again and the same thing happens.

Does anybody heard about this behavior?. I can't solve it yet!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question seems like it might be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158130/visual-studio-2005-designer-moves-controls-and-resizes-form/4404710#4404710

Answer (score 1):

Ive not seen that behaviour, but this may help you troubleshoot it:

Copy the form's .cs & designer.cs files to a safe place, then open the form designer. Save the changes it makes. Then use a Diff program to see what it is actually changing. Finding out what it is changing is may give you some ideas about how to avoid it happening. (It may well be "correcting" something or reformatting some text - if so, is likely that the source code can be edited by hand to a format that won't trigger the change in future).