# Undesireable Windows Form Resizing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've been working on a project in Visual Studio 2010 creating a large Windows form using C#. What's getting me is that whenever I feel I need a change to the layout of the form and open it in designer view, it will resize to a slightly smaller set of dimensions. Every time it does this I have to restore the size and relocate some of the panels as they get out of position. Would anyone know why this keeps happening? I've had to keep the designer window closed when not working in it because it will resize when I launch the project in Visual Studio, as well, if the view was left open when I last closed the project.

Comment: May I ask why I've been downvoted? I would seriously like to stop Visual Studio from resizing the form window on its own.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer, too... upvoted you to even things out :)

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for that answer too. Here is something that may be similar to your question? [visual studio 2005 designer moves controls and resizes Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158130/visual-studio-2005-designer-moves-controls-and-resizes-form/4404710#4404710)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my project too.

Form Properties;

- AutoScaleMode = Font
- ControlBox = False
- FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle
- MaximizeBox = False
- MinimizeBox = False
- ShowIcon = False
- ShowInTaskbar = False
- StartPosition = CenterParent

I set my form size to 485:210. I save and close the form. I re-opened the form and size of the form changed to 481:206. I had no idea why this was happening.

First I searched around and couldn't find the solution.

- AutoScaleMode set to Font in my forms.
- Windows resolution is 1360 x 768.

I tried AutoScaleMode properties set to None, but the form size changed again. I changed Dpi but the result was same. I tried to use Docking for all controls in the form, but the result was same. I tried all answers which I found in stackoverflow.

I dont have any problem with my other forms. Then I realize that my other forms has ControlBox.

***Then I set ControlBox properties to True***. The size of the form not changed this time.