# Visual studio designer keeps resizing the controls every time i reopen the designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I have a listbox in panel which is docked fill in tablelayoutpanel column.

When I set the listbox anchor to Top, Left. it is not resizing automatically when I reopen the designer file. But when I set the listbox anchor to Top,Left,Bottom. Everytime when I reopen the designer, ListBox resizes automatically.

I tried changing the autoscalemode of the form to all its properties. Still no luck.

How do I fix this behaviour in VS Windows Forms?

Comment: What exactly is happening that you think shouldn't be happening, or isn't happening that you think should?

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem.  If you anchor to top, left, and bottom then your listbox will be resized whenever the form is resized.  If you don't want that to happen, don't dock to the bottom.  If I am misunderstanding, please let me know!

Comment: I have a tablelayoutpanel which expands automatically when the form expands, there is a panel docked fill to one of the tablelayoutpanel column. I dropped a listbox in panel and i am setting the anchor to top,left and bottom because i want the listbox to expand automatically when the table layout panel expands.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 I usually anchor to the top and left and then set Dock=Fill when I want something to fill its spot in the TableLayoutPanel.  But that probably works out to the same thing.  I still don't understand what your problem is though.  Are other controls resizing that shouldn't be?

Comment: No. Only listbox resizes, i have labels, buttons and textboxes also in the panel

Comment: This is possibly related to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517352/undesireable-windows-form-resizing-in-visual-studio-2010?rq=1).