# VS2010 Designer is breaking resx files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

If anyone have any clue at all, it would be welcome. I got the same problem last year, and we end up ghosting my computer. 9 month later, I got the problem again ...

Whenever I open a project, if I open a form in my designer, the resx files get automaticly checked-out and modified as I open it.

[image: auto check out]

( we have an auto-check out policy at work that force you to check out a file WHEN YOU MODIFY IT, to avoid 2 programmer working on the same stuff. its not support to check out when I'm just "reading" a file. I just compared with other poeple, and it works correctly for everyone but me.)

[image: Broken ResX file]

The above image is what I saw when I debug the program, I didnt checked-in anything. I just did a getlatest, and debugged.

Whenever I open a form, The width property of the form gets overwritted down to 770 pixel instead of the regular 950. the image data used on our button gets resize smaller too by ±10 pixel width and height.

---

Another exemple : this is what I saw when I compared my last resx file checked in from last night.  I didnt modified the design or moved anything in the designer at all, it just happened to be open while I was working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old bug date from vs2003 ...

my screen DPI wasnt the same as the guy who 1st build the winform ... which cause the desginer to replace all the anchors et fonts et whatnot ...

check out this post for more details : [DPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158130/visual-studio-2005-designer-moves-controls-and-resizes-form/1159310#1159310)

Answer (score 1):

remove the .suo file?

while the solution is closed remove the .suo file and then open the solution to recreate it. it may be restoring the screen sizes from when you last opened the file.

Comment: I didnt had any .suo files associate with the whole program, or this project,

Comment: really? thats strange the .suo are hidden files are you displaying hidden files?

Comment: true enough, I deleted it and I,m checking if its still corrupting my resx right now.

Comment: it seems to have help a bit ... I'm not doing any auto-checkout and modifying forms just by debugging them anymore, but it seems the control is still out of position on my form. I'll get a coworker to clean the form and check-in a new version, i'll see it this will help.

Comment: seems like this wasnt the problem, but thanks anyway for the help.