# Visual Studio 2015 WinForm project changes controls layout randomly

Tags: c#, layout, visual-studio-2015, controls

I'm struggling to maintain my project written in C# (started in VS2010). Every now and then (there is no key or I didn't notice it) Visual studio "rearrange" my controls layout completely. It resizes and moves controls without touching it. Most of the time it "moves" controls out of scope (negative values) and resize it to zero.

[image: Diff screen shoot]

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Never happened to me before. How about remove VS, clean it, and install it from scratch using the latest VS2015 Update 3. Do you have some addon to your VS ?

Comment: Reinstalling is not the solution. Already did it! Using latest Update and ReSharper.

Comment: What happen if you disable ReSharper ? Probably that is the problem.

Comment: Nop, not a Resharper problem... It's definitely the VisualStudio 2015 problem. We could discuss that whole week but I'm searching for a long time problem solution. :)

Comment: I use also vs2005-vs2015 with resharper in winxp-win10 and never seen this before. How about test it on another clean pc?

Comment: PC was cleaned (new PC), only 3 weeks old. Is basically the same problem as stated here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158130/visual-studio-2005-designer-moves-controls-and-resizes-form/1159310#1159310) the only problem is that none of the solutions provided in thread works! :(

Comment: Ok, then the only way is to make a bug report to MS