# Why does Visual Studio 2017 keep messing up my form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, button

I am working on a multi form Windorms application in Visual Studio 2017.
I have a small form set up properly (pic 1,)
If I close the window and open it again Visual Studio messes up my form for no apparent reason. (pic 2,)

The only way I managed to keep this from happening when running my program is setting the buttons location at runtime in code.

This does not happen on any other form by the way.

[image: Pic 1:]

[image: Pic 2:]

The form is a `FixedToolWindow` and the buttons are just regular buttons. They are anchored to the bottom left and bottom right.

I can post the Designer code if anyne needs it.

Why does VS do this? Is there something I can do to make it stop?

Small edit: I closed and opened the form again, and it just keeps raising the buttons higher.

Small edit #2: After reopening the form, I can press `ctrl + z` to undo and the buttons go back to their original places, so it looks like this sis happening when I open the form again maybe.

Comment: What is the value of the property AutoScaleMode of your form?

Comment: No idea; but I can't strongly recommend enough considering a move to WPF (for so many reasons). It definitely doesn't have *that* problem

Comment: @Steve It's on `Grow only` as by default

Comment: I had a similar problem that was caused by `.AutoScaleMode`. But you could also use a `TableLayout` design the form

Comment: Try setting it to AutoScaleMode=None

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for the comment, I do WPF from time to time but I'm not a huge fan.

Comment: @Steve Sorry I misread your question, autoscalemode is on `Font` I'll try that

Comment: @Steve I tried but it sadly made no difference it seems

Comment: @WolfyD If you ever want to discuss it, I'm sure the regulars in the WPF room would be happy to change your mind :) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: @BradleyDotNET heh thanks, I'll consider it :)

Comment: In this question there are numerous 'possible' solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158130/visual-studio-2005-designer-moves-controls-and-resizes-form

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I'll look into this, I might have to put the buttons in a panel and use docking or something

Comment: Well in the end that did work, I placed my buttons in a Panel and now they just stay put in there... Still I remember this being an issue once before when I was using VS 2013 so I guess this is an old bug... Thanks for the help everyone!